# Reliably write from multiple threads to one PrintWriter

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, io

I'm running into an issue where I have multiple threads that write to the same PrintWriter and not all the data is getting written to the file. I know the multi-threaded part is working correctly since I can print everything to the console. Synchronizing the write statements does not seem to be working. What could be the problem?

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);

for (Integer i : map.keySet()) {
    final Collection<String[]> set = map.get(i);
    pool.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        StringBuffer sb = Matcher.performCollectionMatch(params);
        synchronized (this) {
            resultFile.print(sb); //this is a PrintWriter - it does NOT capture all sb
            resultFile.flush();
            System.out.print(sb); //this actually prints out ALL sb
        }
        }
    });
} //FOR loop
```

Comment: is your pool size big enough?

Comment: I assume it is. I set it to 10 threads, and have not run out of memory. Also, I know the threads are doing the work correctly, since I can capture the output from System.out and it is accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you close the `PrintWriter` after the pool stops?

```
pool.shutdown();
final boolean terminated = pool.awaitTermination(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
if (!terminated) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("pool shutdown timeout");
}

resultFile.close();
```

Comment: What I didn't realize was that pool.shutdown() does not block until all threads are complete. Simple fix: 
`
pool.shutdown();
while (!pool.isTerminated) { }
resultFile.close();
`

Comment: This `while` use a lot of CPU. `awaitTermination` does the same but use 0% CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will modify accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

For synchronization to work, you should use the same object for all threads, e.g.:

```
...
synchronized (resultFile) {
...
```

Comment: Initially that is exactly what I tried (my understanding of synchronized statements). However, it wrote even fewer results to the file.

Comment: Something else is quite wrong then. This answer correctly fixes the synchronization here, which was not actually protecting access to the stream.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution is to ensure there is only one thread in the pool.  This way you don't need to synchonize writing as there is only one thread.

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadedPool();

for (Integer i : map.keySet()) {
    final Collection<String[]> set = map.get(i);
    pool.executor(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            StringBuilder sb = Matcher.performCollectionMatch(params);
            resultFile.print(sb); //this is a PrintWriter - it does NOT capture all sb 
            System.out.print(sb); //this actually prints out ALL sb
        }
    });
} //FOR loop
```

It is quite likely the bottle neck is you disk access so adding more threads may not help.

Comment: @kirdie IMHO the purpose of multi-threading is to maximise performance, not use all the cores I have.  Often the optimal number of threads is one. ;)